# Python importing a function with file's name contained in a variable

Tags: python, import

Hi I have a directory in the same folder as my main script called 'actions' in this folder there are several scripts that may be used at any time by the main script. I am at the point where I have the name of the script in the form of a string in a variable called VAR (for the sake of example). I would like to be able to import this file using the variable.

Comment: Why don't the normal `import` or `from ... import` forms work for your use case?  Trying to do dynamic imports almost always means there's a design flaw in your program.

Comment: the program I am doing is working with, for lack of a better word, plugins that are all contained in one folder. Sorry if that wasn't very helpful but to me it seems to justify why I am dynamically importing scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aim is simply to execute the files, you can use

```
with open(filename) as f:
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, "exec"))
```

or the Python 2.x function `execfile()`.

If you actually want to import the modules using the full import machinery, you need an `__init__.py` in the directory `actions`, and can use something like

```
module = __import__("actions.foo")
```

to import `actions/foo.py`.

Comment: Or the methods in `importlib`.  But still, the likely scenario is that there's a design flaw here.

Comment: @sr2222: The usual use case is some kind of plugin system where plugins might be dynamically added to the directory.  Seems fine to me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yea its basically a plugin thing. For fun during the summer I tried to make a text based siri that basically uses, well, plugins which can be added to the folder at any time. Anywas it is literally about to be done so thanks so much. I would hug you if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `__import__` function

```
__import__(str)
```

Comment: thanks this worked but the other answer gets the check mark because it was much more in-depth of an answer mostly because he talked about the __init__.py which I was having trouble with before, and for anyone else who reads this page, it is very helpful info

Answer (score 0):

2021 update:
Python3.9.5's `__import__()` includes this message:

> Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python interpreter and not for general use, it is better to use importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module.

So it then becomes:

```
from importlib import import_module
import_module(modulename_or_relative_filename)
```