# Python: Import function from file whose name is a variable

Tags: python, getattr, python-importlib

I have a file `./model_scripts/medians.py` containing a function `predict_volume()`. [Output of `tree` in the bash terminal given below]

```
 model_scripts
 ├── __init__.py
 ├── medians.py
 └── ...
```

I need to import this function into another python script where the name of the python script from which the function must be imported (i.e. `medians.py`) is in the form of a string variable. The code I have written is:

```
model_name = 'medians'
...
model = getattr(__import__('model_scripts'), model_name)
vol = model.predict_volume()
```

But I get the following error at the first line:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'medians'
```

Upon reading other answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766141/python-importing-a-function-with-files-name-contained-in-a-variable)), I added a `__init__.py` to the `model_scripts` directory. But I am still getting the above error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python?rq=1) answer suggested using `importlib`:

```
import importlib
model_name = 'medians'
...
model = importlib.import_module('model_scripts.'+model_name)
vol = model.predict_volume()
```

Would appreciate any insights on why the first approach does not work but the second does.

Comment: The first is equivalent to `from model_scripts import medians` and the second is equivalent to `import model_scripts.medians`, which are two different requests.

Comment: @cdhowie: Isn't what I'm doing by typing ` model = getattr(__import__('model_scripts'), model_name)` the same as `model = model_scripts.medians`?

Comment: It should be. This assumes that `model_scripts` even exports `medians`.  Does `from model_scripts import medians` work the way you think it should?

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, it works as expected. However, if the module name 'medians' is a string variable, I cannot import it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for `__import__` here is using `fromlist` along with it.

The following works (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist)):

```
model = getattr(__import__('model_scripts', fromlist=[model_name]), model_name)
```